# Problem with button element in IE8 (maybe above)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

`<button>` element lead itself like element `<a>`.

When I over mouse on button, i see next: in status line at bottom i see current url.
After I click on it javascript triggers but then page reloads.

In other browsers all is okay.

Comment: Can you show your markup, so we can better understand what you're talking about?

Comment: @Natethenoob: no signatures or "hi" lines, please.

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to put `<button>` elements inside `<a>` elements.

However, if you need to do it, disable bubbling of the click event on the button:

```
$('a > button').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
})
```

(needs jQuery)

Answer (score 0):

Button element is by default submit button that's why the page "reloads".

Two possible solutions: either add `type="button"` like this:

```
<button type="button" onclick="next();">Next</button>
```

Or add `return false;` to the onclick:

```
<button onclick="next(); return false;">Next</button>
```